# Parallel reactions for one product

Tags: reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, kinetics, concentration, reaction-order

For me it is clear how I could solved the kinetic of a parallel reaction like this

[image]

[image]

But, how can I solve if this would be the case:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As two separate first order reactions and then sum to get total A.

Comment: If it is clear for you how to solve the former, it must be clear for you how to solve the latter.